# There is an error in XML document (0, 0) in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have source code:

```
string epcisSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EPCISSettings"];

if (!epcisSettings.EndsWith(@"\"))
{
    epcisSettings += @"\";
}

string filePath = epcisSettings + ((BizStepCode)bizStepItems.BizStepCode).ToString().ToUpper() + ".xml";
File.WriteAllText(filePath, "");
LogWriter.LogOutput(LogType.INFO, "DAOEpcRecords.addEpcRecords", "EPCISSettingsFilePath = " + filePath);

LocationMasterRecords locationMasterRecords = new DAOLocationMasterRecords(this.connectionString).getLocationMasterRecords();
LocationMasterRecords.LocationMasterItems locationMasterItems = locationMasterRecords.LocationMasterList.Where(q => q.LocationCode == bizStepItems.LocationCode).First();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
{

    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObjectEventType));

    ObjectEventType objectEventType = new ObjectEventType();
    objectEventType = (ObjectEventType)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
    objectEventType.epcList = epcList.ToArray();
    objectEventType.eventTime = DateTime.Now;
    objectEventType.eventTimeZoneOffset = DateTime.Now.ToString("zzz");
    ReadPointType readPointType = new ReadPointType();
    readPointType.id = "1";
    objectEventType.readPoint = readPointType;
    BusinessLocationType businessLocationType = new BusinessLocationType();
    businessLocationType.id = "12";
    objectEventType.bizLocation = businessLocationType;

    EPCISDocumentType epcisDoc = new EPCISDocumentType();
    epcisDoc.EPCISBody = new EPCISBodyType();
    epcisDoc.EPCISBody.EventList = new object[1];
    epcisDoc.EPCISBody.EventList[0] = objectEventType;

    byte[] bsRequest = EpcSerializer.ToEPCISDocumentTypeBytes(epcisDoc);
    HttpCli client = new HttpCli();
    client.Open(Properties.Settings.Default.CoreCaptureServiceURI);
    client.DoPost(bsRequest, "text/xml; charset=utf-8", null, 60000);

    if (client.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        throw new Exception("HTTP " + client.StatusCode + " ");
    }
}
```

This is class error: `objectEventType = (ObjectEventType)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);`

There is an error in XML document (0, 0). I tried it in many ways but it does not run. Below is my xml file, I found the answer on many different forums but when put in the code it does not work.

```
<epcis:EPCISDocument xmlns:epcis="urn:epcglobal:epcis:xsd:1" xmlns:cbvmda="urn:epcglobal:cbv:mda">          
     <EPCISBody>                    
         <EventList>                
             <ObjectEventType>          
                <eventTime>2018-04-10T15:00:02.449Z</eventTime>     
                <eventTimeZoneOffset>+09:00</eventTimeZoneOffset>       
                 <epcList>      
                     <epc>urn:epc:id:giai:1234567.1111</epc>    
                     <epc>urn:epc:id:giai:1234567.222</epc> 
                     <epc>urn:epc:id:giai:1234567.33</epc>  
                 </epcList>     

                 <bizStep>urn:epcglobal:cbv:bizstep:commissioning</bizStep>     
                 <disposition>urn:epcglobal:cbv:disp:active</disposition>       
                 <readPoint>        
                    <id>urn:epc:id:sgln:0400001.00300.0</id>    
                </readPoint>        
                <bizLocation>       
                    <id>urn:epc:id:sgln:04000001.00300.0</id>   
                </bizLocation>      
                 <extension>        
                     <ilmd> 
                         <cbvmda:itemExpirationDate>2015-03-15</example:expiry>
                         <cbvmda:lot>A123</example:lot>
                     </ilmd>    
                 </extension>       
             </ObjectEventType>         
         </EventList>               
     </EPCISBody>                   
</epcis:EPCISDocument>
```

Comment: Your problem is pretty obvious. You have to serialize/deserialize the xml-*root*-node, which is `EPCISDocument` in your case.

Comment: Can you say clearer? @HimBromBeere

Comment: When reading an xml-file you surely have to read the *entire* file. not just a part of it. Your xml-document begins on `EPCISDocumen`.

Comment: I changed:
 XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EPCISDocumentType));
                        ObjectEventType objectEventType = new ObjectEventType();
                        EPCISDocumentType epcisDoc = new EPCISDocumentType();
                        epcisDoc = (EPCISDocumentType)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
but it does not work

Comment: Can you take some time to revise that code?

Comment: As already mentioned in the comments to your (deleted) answer please put all information *directly into the question*. Don´t use comments for that, as they are hard to read. Furthermore don´t whrite "it doesn´t work", but instead what exactly you get and what you expect instead. All that is also mentioned on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask